# Working with Arrays in JQuery - Adding, Deleting, Duplicate entries

Tags: jquery, html, arrays, unique, addition

I'm trying to add div id's to a jquery array when they are clicked.  There is also a toggle on the divs that apply a 'selected' css class.  I only want to add id's to the div when the selected css class is active on the div.  In addition to this I'm having an issue with duplicates in the array.  I thought I was using the unique function properly, but I guess not.

Here is the HTML I'm using:

```
<div class="content">
            <a href="#item3" class="panel multi"><div class="circle skinCare multi" id="acne" style="top:10px;left:265px"><div class="inner_circle" id="acne">ACNE/</br>BLEMISHES</div></div></a>
            <a href="#item3" class="panel multi"><div class="circle skinCare multi" id="dry_skin" style="top:255px;left:10px"><div class="inner_circle" id="dry_skin">DRY SKIN</div></div></a>
            <a href="#item3" class="panel multi"><div class="circle skinCare multi" id="oily_skin" style="top:90px;left:100px"><div class="inner_circle" id="oily_skin">OILY SKIN/LARGE PORES</div></div></a>
            <a href="#item3" class="panel multi"><div class="circle skinCare multi" id="aging" style="top:90px;left:430px"><div class="inner_circle" id="aging">WRINKLES/</br>AGING</div></div></a>
            <a href="#item3" class="panel multi"><div class="circle skinCare multi" id="irritation" style="top:255px;left:510px"><div class="inner_circle" id="irritation">SENSATIVE SKIN/IRRITATION</div></div></a>
            <a href="#item3" class="panel multi"><div class="circle skinCare multi" id="dark_spots" style="top:430px;left:100px"><div class="inner_circle" id="dark_spots">DARK SPOTS</div></div></a>
        </div>
```

Here is the jQuery:

```
var skinCare=[];
$('.skinCare').click(function(){
    //var index = "Skin Care";
    if($('div.skinCare').css('background-color') == 'rgb(255, 0, 0)'){
        skinCare.push(event.target.id);

    }
    var skinCare1 = $.unique(skinCare);
    alert(skinCare1);

});
```

It outputs this into the alert:

```
acne, aging, acne, acne, irritation
```

I need it to add an id to the array if something is selected and delete it from the array if it is deselected.

Comment: But `event.target.id` is always nothing

Answer (score 1):

`$.unique` is well documented to be for DOM elements only:

Excerpt from docs:

> Description: Sorts an array of DOM elements, in place, with the duplicates removed. Note that this only works on arrays of DOM elements, not strings or numbers.

API Reference: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/

Use `$.inArray()` instead to check values

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var skinCare=[];
$('.skinCare').on("click", function(){
    //var index = "Skin Care";
    var id = $(this).attr('id')
    if ($.inArray(id, skinCare) == -1)
        skinCare.push(id);
    else
        skinCare.splice( $.inArray(id, skinCare), 1 );

    alert(skinCare);
});
```

It will push the id of the div onto the array if it isn't there already, and remove it if it is. Could be done on the toggle event as well I think.